# Can I use Serilog Enrichers to get Machine / Hostname Name?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have been searching on how I can get client hostname/computer name using ASP.Net Core MVC using .net 3.1 .

There are threads here on SO but most of them are not working on intranet apps (clients used VPN to connect to network).

I've seen some suggestion on some thread to use  [Serilog Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-environment).
My question is how can I use this one? Can I really get the Machine Name (value passed on the application to db) using this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Try this configuration on:

```
"Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" ],
"Enrich": [ "WithMachineName", "WithClientIp" ]
```

You'd need the nuget package [Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo/)

**UPDATE:**
You can also write the logs directly to the database using one of the database sinks. For eg, to write to a MSSQL database, you could use the sink here: [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](https://github.com/serilog-mssql/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver)

This gives you control over what properties and you want to log including Client Info

Comment: Should I be able to get it and pass it to a variable and store it on a database?